# MySQL - Generate a counter of xx rows

Tags: mysql

I just want to generate xx rows with a number to each one, something like that :

```
SELECT 1 TO 50
```

The resultset contains 50 rows, numeroted from 1 to 50

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a stored procedure:

```
delimiter #

create procedure my_counter(lower_bound INT, upper_bound INT)
begin

declare v_max int unsigned default upper_bound;
declare v_counter int unsigned default lower_bound;

CREATE TABLE temp_my_counter (id int);

   while v_counter <= v_max do
    INSERT INTO temp_my_counter SELECT v_counter;   
    set v_counter=v_counter+1;
  end while;

SELECT temp_my_counter.id FROM temp_my_counter;    
DROP TABLE temp_my_counter;

end #    
delimiter ;
```

Then `call my_counter(2, 5);` will return

```
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way :-

```
select 1 union
select 2 union
select 3 union
select 4 union
...
select 50;
```

Or, you can consider to write a procedural or user-defined-function

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
select @count := @count + 1
from (select @count := 0) count
cross join (select 1 from information_schema.TABLES limit 10) as ten
cross join (select 1 from information_schema.TABLES limit 10) as hundred
cross join (select 1 from information_schema.TABLES limit 10) as thousand
cross join (select 1 from information_schema.TABLES limit 10) as ten_thousand
limit 50;
```

or this (which is quicker):

```
select @count := @count + 1
from (select @count := 0) count
cross join (select 1 union all select 1) as two
cross join (select 1 union all select 1) as four
cross join (select 1 union all select 1) as eight
cross join (select 1 union all select 1) as sixteen
cross join (select 1 union all select 1) as thirty_two
cross join (select 1 union all select 1) as sixty_four
cross join (select 1 union all select 1) as one_two_eight
cross join (select 1 union all select 1) as two_five_six
cross join (select 1 union all select 1) as five_twelve
cross join (select 1 union all select 1) as one_thousand_twenty_four
limit 50;
```